# Rails: How to create a link that loads the page with print.css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, printing

I have a rather simple question that I can't seem to answer. In my Ruby on Rails application I want to create a link with link_to that loads a page with the print stylesheet instead of the normal stylesheet. So, let's say a normal link_to looks like this:

```
link_to "Page", page_path, :target => "_blank"
```

I want that the page is then rendered in a new window with the print.css so that the user sees exactly what he or she will be printing. I already tried to set the media to print, but I can't find how to do this.

Also I know that I can directly use call_to_function with javascript print, but I need the website to be opened in a new tab with the print stylesheet in use. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a separate master page for your printable pages. You may include whatever css you like in the header so for example:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "print" %>
```

One caveat is the asset pipeline and Sprockets. I believe Rails will render this correctly in production but it is one thing to watch out for.

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "print", media: "print" %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing something like a print.html.erb in the layouts folder and then in the controller watch for a param and if it is true, then render the print layout instead of the application layout, but that seems unnecessary for just changing the stylesheet. So I was hoping for a simpler way that tells the browser to use the print.css instead of the screen.css for the page being loaded. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to see what the page will look like with print media styles applied is to use the browser's built in print preview. Of course, that requires knowledge on the part of the user that you may not want to depend on.

Another alternative is suggested here:
http://trentrichardson.com/2006/12/25/print-preview-with-css-and-javascript/